# No puedo aplicar un efecto en todas las pantallas con react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Tengo un problema para aplicar un efecto que se aplica cuando hago scroll en la pantalla y que debe aplicarse si la propiedad es true.
Cuando inicia la app y la navego funciona, pero cuando lo hago por segunda vez en programs falla, es decir, lo sigue aplicando pese a que le estoy pasando false.. por que falla? Gracias!
este es mi codigo:

app.js -- > aqui le paso la propiedad true para que aplique o no el efecto sobre el componente float player.

```
<Route path="/" exact render={(props) => <Home {...props} FloatPlayerVisible={true} />}/>

<Route path="/programas" exact render={(props) => <Programs {...props} FloatPlayerVisible={false} />} />
```

Home.js recibe el parametro y lo aplica sobre el componente.

```
<FloatPlayer  handleEffectScroll={this.props.FloatPlayerVisible} />
```

Program.js tambien lo recibe

```
export default function ProgramSection(props){


    return(
            <div>
                <ProgramsSection handleEffectScroll={props.FloatPlayerVisible} />
                <FloatPlayer handleEffectScroll={props.FloatPlayerVisible}/>
            </div>

        )
    }
```

Y finalmente en FloatPlayer mediante jquery lo aplico.

floatplayer.js

```
export default class FloatPlayer extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
    }

    componentDidMount() {

        if (this.props.handleEffectScroll == true) {

            $('.float-player').addClass('hide-play');

            $(window).scroll(function () {
                if ($(document).scrollTop() > 400) {
                    $('.float-player').removeClass('hide-play').addClass('show-play')
                } else {
                    $('.float-player').removeClass('show-play').addClass('hide-play')
                }
            })
        } else {
            $('.float-player').removeClass('hide-play').addClass('show-play')
        }

    }

return (
            <React.Fragment>

                <div className="row float-player"> 
                  .....codigo
                </div>
            </React.Fragment>
)
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Intenta hacerlo en el método componentWillReceiveProps.

```
export default class FloatPlayer extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
    }

    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
        if (nextProps.handleEffectScroll == true) {
            $('.float-player').addClass('hide-play');
            $(window).scroll(function () {
                if ($(document).scrollTop() > 400) {
                    $('.float-player').removeClass('hide-play').addClass('show-play')
                } else {
                    $('.float-player').removeClass('show-play').addClass('hide-play')
                }
            })
        } else {
            $('.float-player').removeClass('hide-play').addClass('show-play')
        }
    }

    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <div className="row float-player"> 
                .....codigo
            </div>
        </React.Fragment>
    )
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Juan, but dosen t work..

Answer (score 0):

El problema era que como estaba aplicando el scroll con jquey sobre window una vez que lo aplicaba no lo estaba elinando dentro del else, lo solucione agregando un

$(window).off('scroll')

muchas gracias!